# Azure Alerts are automatically disabled after they were working for a while

Tags: azure-monitoring

We have defined **alerts** in our **azure app service** and they were working correctly for some time. At some point they **stop** wokring and 7 days later they were even **disabled**.
The activity log is showing the following information :

```
Alert: Low imaging cache usability is disabled by the System due to : Alert has been failing consistently with the same exception for the past 7 days. reasonThe request had some invalid properties
```

Although the queries are executing **correctly**. The **permissions** are right how they should be.

Any idea what could we check? What are these **invalid properties**?

We **manually** enable the alerts and after same period they are disabled again for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is your alert ending with a semicolon? Have you been able to solve this issue?

What we found out:
If a query ends with a semicolon, then Microsoft Azure says that the alert has some invalid properties. But if we open it in the log analytics workspace, the query can be executed properly.

After removing the semicolon end of the query, it works on both the alert configuration page and the log analytics workspace page.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your questions. Our query doesn't ends with semicolon. We didn't do anything special for this problem and I can say that it is working correctly now. 
   My assumption is that colleagues might have been updating something that we were using in this particular query. But I have no prove for this.

Comment: In the meantime we got an official answer from Microsoft on our problem:
"Generally, Log Search Alerts service modifies the query in runtime to allow some optimizations for alerting. Queries that end with semi-colon could not be modified as appending any expression to them will result in KQL syntax error which would cause this behavior"